# Make MediaWiki show real names instead of usernames

Tags: php, mediawiki

I want to show users' real names (when they have one) instead of their usernames. I have already tried some extensions but they are deprecated. I am running MediaWiki 1.26alpha.

The reason I want to show this is, I am running an internal wiki for my corporation with LDAP login. But now they are migrating to a single LDAP/AD and to avoid complications all employees must login with their employee ID, not a username. This however makes no sense to show in my wiki, so I want them to login with the ID as a username but instead that I want their real name to be displayed.

Comment: This is what the [user_real_name](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_table#user_real_name) field, controlled by a user preference, is for. Are you populating it? I see it's used at least in action=credits and action=info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Category:Real name display extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Real_name_display_extensions) has a bunch of extensions doing something along these lines, most of which are not deprecated (although some are rather old).